# Many-To-Many LINQ "IN" Query

Tags: asp.net, linq

Edit: Both the answers below work. My problem was due to using the NHibernate LINQ provider
like this:

```
from parks in Session.Linq<Park>()
```

instead of like this:

```
from parks in Session.Linq<Park().AsEnumerable()
```

---

I have a class called Park which has an  of Amenities. I want to create a LINQ query that returns all Park objects which contain every Amenity in a list. So given:

```
List<Park> Parks(IList<Amenity> amenities)
{
   // I want a query that would look like this (if this worked)
   // return all Park objects that have all of the given amenities

  var query = from parks in db.Parks
              where parks.Amenities.Contains(amenities)
              select parks;
}
```

This query:

```
var query = from parks in Session.Linq<Park>()
    where amenities.All(a => parks.Amenities.Contains(a))
    select parks;
```

doesn't work.

Here's more of my code for context:

Mapping classes(I"m using Fluent NHibernate)

```
public ParkDBMap()
{
 Id(x => x.ParkId).Column("ParkId").GeneratedBy.HiLo("0").UnsavedValue(0);
 Map(x => x.Name, "Name");
 this.HasManyToMany<Amenity>(x => x.Amenities)
 .Table("ParksMaps_ParkAmenities")
.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
}


public AmenityDBMap()
{
 Id(x => x.AmenityId).Column("AmenityId").GeneratedBy.HiLo("0").UnsavedValue(0);
 Map(x => x.Name, "Name");
}
```

Test method:

```
public void ListParksByAmenity()
{
// Create Parks
int parkCount = 10;
CreateParks(parkCount);

// Create Amenities
Amenity restrooms = new Amenity();
restrooms.Name = "Restrooms";
ParksRepos.SaveAmenity(restrooms);

Amenity tennis = new Amenity();
tennis.Name = "Tennis Courts";
ParksRepos.SaveAmenity(tennis);

Amenity dogs = new Amenity();
dogs.Name = "Dogs Allowed";
ParksRepos.SaveAmenity(dogs);

// Add amenities to parks
IList<Park> parks = ParksRepos.Parks();

parks[0].AddAmenity(dogs);
parks[0].AddAmenity(tennis);
parks[0].AddAmenity(restrooms);
ParksRepos.SavePark(parks[0]);

parks[4].AddAmenity(tennis);
parks[4].AddAmenity(restrooms);
ParksRepos.SavePark(parks[4]);

parks[9].AddAmenity(restrooms);
ParksRepos.SavePark(parks[4]);

IList<Amenity> amenityList = new List<Amenity>() { restrooms};
List<Park> restroomsParks = ParksRepos.Parks(amenityList);

// three parks have restrooms
Assert.AreEqual(1, restroomsParks.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(parks[0].Name, restroomsParks[0].Name);

amenityList = new List<Amenity>() { dogs, tennis, restrooms };
List<Park> allAmenities = ParksRepos.Parks(amenityList);

// only one park has all three amenities
Assert.AreEqual(3, allAmenities.Count);

}
```

I have three tables. A "Parks" table, an "Amenities" table, and a many-to-many table that has two columns, a park id and an amenity id.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Park> Parks(IList<Amenity> amenities)
{   
  var query = from parks in db.Parks
              where amenities.All(a => parks.Amenities.Where(sa => sa.ID == a.ID).Count() == 1)
              select parks;
}
```

Comment: I think this would have worked if I hadn't made a typo in my question.
The Park class has a List property called Amenities, not an Amenity property of the same name. My bad.

Comment: This actually works when I specify "Count()" instead of "Count" at the end. It only worked after modifying my code, though. I was using NHibernate to LINQ and had:

    from parks in Session.Linq<Park>()

if I use:
    
    List<Park> AllParks = this.Parks()

and then:

    from parks in All Parks ... rest of query


it works.

Answer (score 1):

This will work .It will return an IEnumerable  . To convert to List you will need to do a ToList()
Note I Assume that Park.Amenity is a List

```
 var x = from Park p in db.Parks where amenities.Except(p.Amenity).Count() == 0 select p;
```

Comment: Park.Amenities is a List. This query returns 0 rows, though.

Comment: Then no park in your Parks collection contains a Amenities list that has every Amenity listed in amenities collection - or there is a misunderstanding.Post your code.

Comment: This works when I don't use the NHibernate LINQ provider. I have to make two queries... pull all the parks from the db, then filter them. I'm not sure what the difference is.